# Designing migration scripts to use transactions with Alembic

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

I've been working on an Alembic upgrade script to use with my SQLAlchemy/SQLite database. The purpose of that script was to change over one column from decimal to integer values. In that process, I learned [SQLite doesn't support](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Why-can-t-SQLite-drop-columns-td64687.html) `DROP COLUMN`. But what's worse is that in dealing with that, Alembic left my tables in a halfway state, where the table I was editing had both the decimal column and integer column.

But this question isn't about how to drop columns. I know how I want to do that now. This questions is about how I can wrap all my DDL statements for an Alembic upgrade/downgrade script, as well as the DLM stuff, into one transaction which can be rolled back if I encounter failures. I want a safe pattern going forward that I can generalize to all my Alembic migrations.

Here's pseudo code for what I'm looking for:

```
def upgrade():
    # get context or connection or something
    # on context/connection/migration context/something do something like
    with context.begin_transaction():

        # do various DDL stuff
        # with various new DDL stuff, do bulk inserts and data manipulation
        # once finally done, commit and end the transaction. roll EVERYTHING back if it fails.
```

What I'm having *a lot* of confusion over is determining the correct way to connect to my db. Do I do something like `alembic.op.get_bind()` and work with the connection there? Do I use `MigrationContext`?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? https://bugs.python.org/issue10740

Comment: @univerio I'm using Alembic 0.9.8

Comment: That's... not what I asked. If you run `python -V` what does it print out? (2.7.10? 3.5.3? 3.6.2? etc)

Comment: I can't read. Running that command inside the virtual env (pipenv) I'm using returns: `Python 3.6.4`